# Import models tasks celery

Tags: python, django, django-models, scheduled-tasks, celery

I'm trying to find out how to import models in my tasks.py in celery.

In the moment my project structure is the following:

```
/mainApp
    -celery_instance
        -__init.py__
        -celery.py
        -tasks.py
    -app
        -settings.py
        -urls.py
        -models.py
    -admin
        -__init.py__
        -views.py
```

What I try is to write a task to check each day if there is a birthday.

Do I need to import models in tasks.py? I tried it, but I get an error. It doesn't recognize my models. From mainApp I can only import settings.py.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It helps if you include the error you get (full traceback).

Comment: There is no "real" error, just in eclipse it says that my model "could not be found".

Comment: So this is a Eclipse-only error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was an error with  my django-celery version.

I found the solution adding in my settings.py

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('celery_instance.tasks',)
```

Comment: What's your django and celery version?